# Unable to process binding - cannot read property of undefined

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have cascading select lists, where selecting the last one should fetch back some filter JSon data for use in the page - basically for updating the contents of the page based on the users selections :

```
function DDLViewModel() {

    var self = this;

    self.ddlDim1 = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.ddlDim2 = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedDim1 = ko.observable();
    self.selectedDim1.subscribe(FetchDim2);
    self.selectedDim2 = ko.observable();
    self.selectedDim2.subscribe(FetchVariant);
    self.prodVariant = ko.observableArray([]);

    function FetchDim2() {
        if(!self.selectedDim1())
        {
            self.ddlDim2.removeAll();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetDims")', // we are calling json method
                dataType: 'json',
                // here we get value of selected dim.
                data: { id: @Model.Product.ProductID,
                    level: 2,
                    head: '@Model.Product.Level2Head',
                    code: self.selectedDim1()
                },
                success: function (dims) {
                    // dims contains the JSON formatted list of dims passed from the controller
                    self.ddlDim2(dims);
                    self.ddlDim3.removeAll();
                    if(dims.length === 1) {
                        self.selectedDim2(dims[0].Value);
                    }else{
                        self.selectedDim2(null);
                    }
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve dims.' + ex);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function FetchVariant() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetVariant")', // we are calling json method
            dataType: 'json',
            // here we get value of selected dim.
            data: { productId: @Model.Product.ProductID,
                Dim1: self.selectedDim1(),
                Dim2: self.selectedDim2()
            },
            success: function (variant) {
                // variant contains the JSON formatted variant data passed from the controller                
                alert('hello');
                var newpv = [];
                newpv.push(variant);
                self.prodVariant(newpv);
                alert('hello again');
            }//,
            //error: function (ex) {
            //    alert('Failed to retrieve variant.' + ex);
            //}
        });

    }

}

//var objVM = new DDLViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(new DDLViewModel);
```

Referencing in my page :

```
        <p>Dim 1 : <strong data-bind="text: selectedDim1"></strong></p>
        <p>Dim 2 : <strong data-bind="text: selectedDim2"></strong></p>
        <p>Variant : <strong data-bind="text: prodVariant().length"></strong></p>
        <p>Variant : <strong data-bind="text: prodVariant()[0].ProductCode"></strong></p>
```

If I omit the last line the drop downs work and the length is displayed as 1 which is correct. With the last line nothing works an I get the error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "text: function
>   (){return prodVariant()[0].ProductCode }" Message: Cannot read
>   property 'ProductCode' of undefined$element.text @

How do I get the data back in, and actually use it in the page? The data is definitely JSon as it's returned from an MVC JSonResult action :

> {"VariantID":19110,"ProductID":0,"ProductCode":"FW13200BR10","Description":"Colour
>   Brown Size 10 
>   ","Level1Code":"Brown","Level1Name":"Brown","Level2Code":"10","Level2Name":"10","Level3Code":"","Level3Name":null,"RRP":0.0000,"SellPrice":21.9500,"QtyAvailable":0,"AvailabilityID":0,"Availability":"Normally
>   despatched within 3-5 working days","AvailableDate":null}

**Edit :**

Got it working by doing this - declare separate observables for the elements I want to replace  :

```
self.ProductCode = ko.observable(@Model.Product.ProductCode);
self.SellPrice = ko.observable('@Model.Product.SellPrice');
```

Then manually populating those from my returned JSon / array :

```
function FetchVariant() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetVariant")', // we are calling json method
                dataType: 'json',
                // here we get value of selected dim.
                data: { productId: @Model.Product.ProductID,
                    Dim1: self.selectedDim1(),
                    Dim2: self.selectedDim2(),
                    Dim3: self.selectedDim3()
                },
                success: function (variant) {
                    // variant contains the JSON formatted variant data passed from the controller
                    var newpv = [];
                    newpv.push(variant);
                    self.ProductCode(newpv[0].ProductCode);
                    self.SellPrice(newpv[0].SellPrice);
                }
            });
```

Not sure if that is the best way but it's working for now - totally new to Knockout so probably a bit of a hack?

Comment: If I add a single observable for Product code and then add :
self.ProductCode(newpv[0].ProductCode); it works but how do I just use the array?

Comment: You need to test whether `prodVariant` has any elements with an `if` binding or by using a `foreach` instead of explicitly indexing it.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: At which point should I check - around where I want to use it in my markup? It does have something in it when my FetchVariant code is called but am I trying to use it too early?

Comment: I would avoid lines like this in the HTML: 
<p>Variant : <strong data-bind="text: prodVariant().length"></strong></p>
        <p>Variant : <strong data-bind="text: prodVariant()[0].ProductCode"></strong></p> - better something like `data-bind="text: FirstProductCode"` which has a computed value that can check for null values etc.